# My linux server "Number of processes created" and "Context switches" are growing incredibly fast

Tags: linux, multithreading, context-switching

**EDIT**: More detailed answers here: https://serverfault.com/questions/454192/my-linux-server-number-of-processes-created-and-context-switches-are-growing

I have a strange behaviour in my server :-/. Is a VPS. When I do `cat /proc/stat`, I can see how each second about 50-100 processes are created and happens about 800k-1200k context switches! All that info is with the server completely idle, no traffic nor programs running.

Top shows 0 load average and 100% idle CPU.

I've closed all non-needed services (httpd, mysqld, sendmail, nagios, named...) and the problem still happens. I do `ps -ALf` each second too and I don't see any changes, only a new `ps` process is created each time and the PID is just the same as before + 1, so new processes are not created, so I thought that process growing in `cat /proc/stat` must be threads (Yes, seems that `processes` in `/proc/stat` counts threads creation too as this states: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8NLgzKEzHQQJ:www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm&hl=es&tbo=d&gl=es&strip=1).

I've changed to `/proc` dir and done `cat [PID]\status` with all PIDs listed with `ls` (Including kernel ones) and in any process `voluntary_ctxt_switches` nor `nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches` are growing at the same speed as `cat /proc/stat` does (just a few tens/second).

I've done `strace -p PID` to all process too so I can see if any process is crating threads or something but the only process that has a bit of movement is `ssh` and that movement is `read`/`write` operations because of the data is sending to my terminal.

After that, I've done `vmstat -s` and saw that `forks` is growing at the same speed `processes` in `/proc/stat` does. As http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork says, each `fork()` creates a new PID but my server PID is not growing!

The last thing I can think of is that all process data that `proc/stat` and `vmstat -s` show is shared with all the other VPS stored in the same machine, but I don't know if that is correct... If someone can throw some light on this I would be really grateful.

Comment: Not a programming question. Try http://serverfault.com

Comment: If your server is serving HTTP web requests with CGIs, you have one process for each HTTP request....

Comment: Ow, that's true @NPE, srry. And Basile, httpd service is stopped.